# Send a PDF URL in a browser to the printer via iframe

Tags: javascript, printing

For current non-IE browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari), I would like to send a PDF document to the printer given a URL to that PDF.

To avoid superfluous windows popping up, I am presently doing this with an `<iframe>` but I would like to close the iframe after the printing is completed, otherwise some browsers will pop up a dialog when one tries to leave the page.

Here is what I have come up with so far (using lodash and jQuery for simplicity):

```
var _print_url, _remove_iframe, _set_print;

_print_url = function(src_url) {
  $("<iframe src='" + src_url + "' type='application/pdf'>").css({
    visibility: 'hidden',
    position: 'fixed',
    right: '0',
    bottom: '0'
  }).on('load', _set_print).appendTo(document.body);
};

_remove_iframe = function(iframe) {
  return $(iframe).parent().find(iframe).detach();
};

_set_print = function() {
  this.contentWindow.print();
/* 
 * Where we could do @contentWindow.close() with a window, we must remove the
 * print iframe from the DOM. We have to engage in some async madness
 * it seems, for no apparent reason other than this won't work
 * synchronously (@cw.print above must be async, it seems) - even though 
 * window.close() appears to work synchronously.
 */
  _.delay(_.partial(_remove_iframe, this), 100);
};
```

Sometimes it seems with Google Chrome the print-dialog ends up showing the PDF correctly, but when one selects the printer and confirms the intention to print it will actually send the contents of the frame's parent page to the printer instead of the PDF itself.

There is a link [suggestions on the Mozilla page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Printing) but this document seems obsolete at the moment. The best example I could find was by reverse-engineering the Amazon Web Services print dialog for invoices, but that opens a window.

One alternative I have considered is [Google Cloud Print](http://www.google.ca/cloudprint/learn/), but obviously this requires the installation of extra software or configuration of a Google Account, neither of which I would wish to impose on users unless necessary.

Are there other examples of how one might print a PDF given a URL, particularly with Javascript and without otherwise superfluous additional browser add-ons or artefacts such as windows popping up?

Comment: This is just a suspicion, but what happens if you call `this.contentWindow.focus()` before calling `print()`?

Comment: @YatinSaraiya It would refer to the iframe. jQuery binds `this` to the element on which an event handler is defined. ([See here, last paragraph in the section](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-handler).)

Answer (score 3):

-- NOTE whit this approach you will never see the popup blocker --

I run in a similar problem wiht an ajax application a couple month ago, the problem was I faced was I need to create the pdf file and store before to send it to print, what I did is the following:

I didnt use iframes. This application works with php `TCPDF` for creating the pdf and `jquery` and `underscore` for the templating system.

you can see the demo video at http://www.screenr.com/Ur07 (2:18 min)

1. Send the information via JSON (ajax) To achieve this because I faced the problem that everything was in ajax, so I couldn't make post with the information, so what I did is to append a hidden `form` to the DOM and then with the target="_blank" make the post to a new window (which you will close a the end of the process).

HTML hidden virtual form

```
<form method='<%= method %>' 
      action="<%= action %>" 
      name="<%= name %>" 
      id="<%= id %>" 
      target="_blank">
    <input type='hidden' name='json' id='<%= valueId %>' />
</form>
```

---

Javascript

```
 function makePost(){
  var _t = _.template(_JS_Templates["print.form.hidden"]); //this the html of the form

  var o = {
    method : "POST",
    action : js_WEB_ + "/print.php",
    name : "print_virtual_form",
    id : "print_virtual_form_id",
    valueId : "print_virtual_value"
  }

 var form = _t(o);
 $(".warp").append(form); //appending the form to the dom

  var json = {
    data : data // some data
  }     

 $("#print_virtual_value").val(JSON.stringify(json)); //assing to the hidden input the value and stringify the json
 $("#print_virtual_form_id").submit(); //make the post submmitting the form
 $("#print_virtual_form_id").remove(); //removing the "virtual hidden form"

}
```

2.- when you receive the json in my case was using php you create whatever you have to create, I did it in this way you can see the php code in this example (is my answer)

[Generate PDF using TCPDF on ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554972/generate-pdf-using-tcpdf-on-ajax-call/13711043#13711043)

3.- And finally in this is where the cool parts come is the response, in this part, I use the php file to write a javascript code saying that have to close the parent windows and report the json answer to an specific function, is kind of callback.

```
switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']){
    case "GET":
        echo "Denied";
    break;

    case "POST":
        if(isset($_POST["json"])){
            if(!empty($_POST["json"])){
                $json = $_POST["json"];             
                $hash = PDF::makePDF($json);
                echo "<script>
                  function init() {
                        //calling callback
                                        //returning control to the previous browser
                                 window.opener.someclass.finish('".$hash."');
                                 window.close();
                    }
                window.onload = init;                       
             </script>";
            }else{
                echo "not json detected";
            }
        }else{
            echo "not json detected";
        }
    break;
```

4.- and for the end with the control in you window browser you can do.

```
var someobject = (function(name){
  //private
  var finish(data){
    //do whatever you want with the json data
  }

   //public
   var $r = {};
   $r.finish = function(data){ 
     finish(data); //you will pass the data to the finish function and that is..!! voila!!
   }

   return $r;
})("someobject");
```

I know is not exactly what you ask but is another approach to the same problem while I think this is little more complex, I can guarantee works in a lot of browser and the users will love the way you do it. They will never see what is happening and they will download the file just how the expect to do it, clicking a link and the saving the file.

Just my two cents and happy coding.

Comment: Thanks very much for adding to the the discussion. This seems to be a real niche problem, so I'm grateful for any thoughts and ideas, and this looks great. Cheers.