# How to get an object with each element passed as a key to a post form?

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a situation where I need to dynamically create a form using javascript, to support some legacy browsers. The data I need to send through the form is currently in an object, so, for example:

```
var data = { name: 'John Doe', age: 35 };
var myForm = document.createElement("form");
myForm.setAttribute("action", myPostActionPath);
myForm.setAttribute("method", "post");

// Append data to the form somehow.

myForm.submit();
```

I feel like this should be something simple to do but I must be missing something obvious. What I would like would be to have something that passed the form the data as a key per property of data, so something like "name=John%20Doe&age=35" for the example above. And I would like to do this *without* having to do the following:

```
var data = { name: 'John Doe', age: 35 };
var myForm = document.createElement("form");
myForm.setAttribute("action", myPostActionPath);
myForm.setAttribute("method", "post");

// NOT what I would like:
var formField1 = document.createElement("input");
formField1.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
formField1.setAttribute("name", "name");
formField1.setAttribute("value", data.name);
myForm.appendChild(formField1);

var formField2 = document.createElement("input");
formField2.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
formField2.setAttribute("name", "age");
formField2.setAttribute("value", data.age);
myForm.appendChild(formField2);

myForm.submit();
```

So, is there any way to append my data that way without looping through data's properties to add each one as a hidden field?

Also, please beware that my data properties could be objects or arrays themselves.

**UPDATE**

This is my current solution, but I was looking for a more straightforward way of passing the data without having to iterate through the data object, but from all the answers here it looks like there's no other way:

```
var data = { name: 'John Doe', age: 35 };
var myForm = document.createElement("form");
myForm.setAttribute("action", myPostActionPath);
myForm.setAttribute("method", "post");

$.each(data, function(name, value) {
    var formInput = document.createElement("input");
    formInput.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    formInput.setAttribute("name", name);
    formInput.setAttribute("value", value);
    myForm.appendChild(formInput);
});

myForm.submit();
```

And just to explain a bit better, I am using this action to download a file after sending some data back to the controller and IE8 and IE9 won't allow a file to be downloaded through an AJAX post so this is a fall-back that allows me to download the file without having to submit the original form which would cause an undesirable full page refresh.

Comment: FYI, that's a JavaScript object, **not** JSON. JSON is a *textual, language-independent* data format.

Comment: Yes, Felix. My object coming down is actually JSON, that was just to simplify the example.

Comment: Doesn't really matter where the data came from.

Comment: Why can't you make an Ajax request btw?

Comment: I can't use Ajax because the post sends back a file to be downloaded and IE8 and IE9 do not allow files to be downloaded through an AJAX post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second attempt what about
//assuming jquery you can modify for pure javascript, im just too lazy and I want to help not make your job :P

```
var data = { name: 'John Doe', age: 35 }

var arrTemplate = [];
arrTemplate.push("<form id='whateverID' action='' method=''");
for (var k in data){
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
         arrTemplate.push("<input type='hidden' name='"+ k +"' value='"+ data[k] +"'>");
    }
}
arrTemplate.push("</form>");

$(document).append(arrTemplate.join(""));
$("#whateverID").submit();
//then you could remove the form if you want to.
```

is this what you want???

Comment: Something similar to this is my current solution, ncubica, I was hoping for something better. I will post the code I'm using.

Comment: I guess it is. Thanks, then. I have posted an updated on the question with what I am originally using.

Answer (score 2):

> So, is there any way to append my data that way without looping through data's properties to add each one as a hidden field?

Unfortunately there is not: [HTMLFormElement API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement).

Answer (score 0):

what about `json.stringify` in an input hidden? then you can decode the json in you server side and have all you want.

here its an similar example which its not answer specifically your question buts its using your technique.[Send a PDF URL in a browser to the printer via iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596043/send-a-pdf-url-in-a-browser-to-the-printer-via-iframe/17714428#17714428)

see the javascript part.

Comment: The idea was to not have to change the server side at all and not have to make it aware of this use case, which is only for legacy browsers.

Comment: why you just simple iterate over the javascript object create dinamically the form and submitted?

Comment: I added another solution